# Why is there a LinkedList in .NET?

Tags: .net

What is the purpose of having a linked list? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx what are it's qualities that make it an important part of the framework.

Comment: see [Linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LinkedList is faster for inserting and removing items at locations other than at the end of the list.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs for more information.

Comment: I guess compared to hash sets the advantages of a linked list would be : 1 faster (lack of hash function) 2 less memory used (hash key) 3 confirmed ordered access in enumeration

Comment: @Basarat Ali: It is difficult to compare them because a Set serves a different purpose than a List. Sets guarantee distinctness, whereas Lists guarantee order. Also, "faster" at what? They're roughly equivalent at traversal (iterating across all the values). Hashset is much faster at lookups of known values (generally speaking) and only marginally slower at most other functions. It would be better to compare LinkedList vs "List" (aka ArrayList), and even then LinkedList only wins out under certain circumstances. Conclusion: Take time to understand LinkedList, and only use it with good reason.

Comment: I completely forgot the distinctness! Marginally "faster" at adding items since a call to GetHashCode is avoided. PS : have you ever used a linked list in production?

Comment: @Basarat Ali: I may have, but at the moment I can't think of when.

Answer (score 4):

Linked lists allow you to insert extra nodes at the start or end of the list, and even in the middle of the list if you already have the node that you want the new value to be before or after.

The downsides compared with something like `List<T>` are:

- Less efficient in memory (a `Node` object per value)
- Less cache coherency (the values may be distributed around memory)
- No random access

Answer (score 2):

Linked lists are faster if you frequently need to add or remove items from known nodes, but you don't need random access.

For more information, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_List),

Comment: Ever so slightly faster than hash sets? I was afraid this was the only reason. That is why I have never seen it used :) Thanks +1

Comment: @Basarat: Yes; they don't have any arrays to resize.

Comment: @Basarat, @SLaks: And you don't have to perform a hash function on the key object.